# How to get element(text) from a table using Selenium WebDriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to get an element (text) from a table using XPATH and then print it, but got the following error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element.

I have waited time but got the same error. How can I get the text?

I've used the following code:

```
account = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_lc_ucLeftMenu_li_1_4"]/a[2]')))
account.click()
time.sleep(3)
portfolio = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_lc_ucLeftMenu_leaf_2_35"]')))
portfolio.click()
time.sleep(3)
sold = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="37ef7b7a-3a62-4d56-a479-29c99031de7e"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[5]')
print('The amount is: {}'.format(sold.text))
sold1 = float(sold.text)
```

Please refer to the attached file- looking to get the highlighted text.

[image]

Comment: Your xpath is going for the 5th not 10th `td`, but that is not the point for the error - Could you improve your question, please and provide some code as text not image.

Comment: The image is the html from which I am trying to get the text. You are right, the highlighted one is the 10th td but, nevertheless , I should have had 612, instead I got the error 'Element not found'.

Comment: That id might be dynamic and might switch.

Comment: @Mardjacku That is clear, but again -> Could you improve your question, please and provide some of your written code as text not image.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) This would help all of us to reproduce the behavior. Many thanks.

Comment: @Arundeep Chohan: the id is not dynamic; after clicking the portfolio, the table and the amount that I am trying to get is as shown in the above picture.

Comment: @HedgeHog: Thanks for your answer; I have modified the question and added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that particular text, the xpath was not the correct one. Instead, I've used the following one:

```
//table/tbody/tr[8]/td[10]
```

the full code will look like this:

```
account = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*    
[@id="ctl00_lc_ucLeftMenu_li_1_4"]/a[2]')))
account.click()
time.sleep(3)
portfolio = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//* 
[@id="ctl00_lc_ucLeftMenu_leaf_2_35"]')))
portfolio.click()
time.sleep(3)
sold = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[8]/td[5]')
print('The amount is: {}'.format(sold.text))
sold1 = float(sold.text)
```